# How to exit the app when user press the menu button on android phonegap

Tags: android, html, cordova

Hi Android Apps Developer around the world,

I am a newbie in android apps development. How to override menu button so that when user press the menu button, there will pop out and exit button for exitting the apps.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Nobody seems to care you tagged `cordova` and `html5` on your question! On your onDeviceReady event you set a listener to the menu button and call `navigator.app.exitApp()`

```
function onDeviceReady(){
   document.addEventListener("menubutton", closeApp, false);
} 

function closeApp(){
   navigator.app.exitApp();
}
```

Be aware that while the other answers don't actually answer your question they have important information:

- Not all devices have a menu button.
- Be sure to notify the user you're closing the app, Adrien approach of showing a dialog is pretty standard and good enough.
- If you try to publish an app that has a close button for iOS  **YOUR APP WILL PROBABLY BE REJECTED**

Comment: Hi @gameower, thank you for answering. How to create a menu exit when user press the menu button. Not just simply exit the apps when pressing the menu button.

Comment: Well, you've got the listener, if you want to do it on html learn [How to add elements to a page](http://www.dustindiaz.com/add-and-remove-html-elements-dynamically-with-javascript/), if you want to do it on android native code [remove the listener and create the menu](http://www.casperweb.in/phonegap/create-android-native-menu-in-phonegap/). If you want someone to do it for you I'm sure you can hire a developer . I can even email you my rates.

Answer (score 0):

Like this way :
EDIT

```
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) {
    // Create your alertDialog
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setTitle("Exit ?")
    .setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
    .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, null)
    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
            //Destroy your current activities
    Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager()
                    .getLaunchIntentForPackage(   getBaseContext().getPackageName() );
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    }).create().show();
    return true;
}
return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
}
```

Hope this help

Comment: hi @adrien cerdan I just implement your code, but the apps did't not exit when i press the yes button.

Answer (score 0):

1. Menu Button is deprecated! (since android 4)
2. Do not exit a App programmatically. Let the android system manage the apps lifecycle! There is no need to exit an app. Indeed you will destroy the Multitasking App context switching (which is the great feature of Android comparing to iOS). So the user can not go back to the current app state (screen / data etc.), because the app will start completely new, the user has to navigate to where he was previously etc.

Answer (score 0):

Android's design does not favor exiting an application by choice, but rather manages it by the OS. You can bring up the Home application by its corresponding Intent:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU)) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("Do you want to Exit?").setCancelable(true)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
              .setNegativeButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                  dialog.dismiss();
                });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
    }
    return true;
}
```